# How to change an image to another image and back to the original?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image

I am working on an ios app and i can't seem to make the character model switch back to the idle state.

I was using wait() and sleep() but they seem not to work, they just remain in the idle image every time I click on the screen.
I also tried using NStimer but i am not really sure how to work it.

What i'm basically doing is a character is standing straight up and when you click the screen he kicks. One image is him standing while the other shows him kicking. I can't figure out how to make him always stand but when you tap on the screen he kicks for two seconds then he goes back to standing.

If you need more info i would be able to show some of the code.

```
    -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
         UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];

         CGPoint aPoint = [myTouch locationInView:self.view];

         if (aPoint.x <160)
        {
         Player.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Person1.png"];
         wait(5);
         Player.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Person2.png"];
         }
         else
         {
          Player2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Person1.png"];
          wait(5);
          Player2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Person2.png"];
         }

     }
```

This is what my friend told me that would work. But it does not.

Comment: Post the relevant code of what you are trying and explain the exact issue you are having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `performSelector`

```
-(IBAction)changeBtn{
   self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"character_kicking"];
   [self performSelector:@selector(changeImage) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];//2sec
}


-(void)changeImage{
  self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"character_standing"];
}
```

or with the timer

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(changeImage)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:NO];
```

Comment: Thanks. Yours helped me understand how NSTimers worked. I was able to use the NSTimer into the touch. Thanks again.